# Получить высоту пользователя над уровнем земли

Tags: android, геолокация

Продумываю одну игру в режиме реального времени. Нужно получить высоту пользователя над уровнем земли. Если координаты возможно получить через Google Location API, то как получить высоту, то есть позицию на оси Z мирового пространства? Или в координатах уже она есть?

Comment: Оффтоп: Я вспомнил про игру на iOS что то вроде " Let it fly to paradase" или что-то подобное, когда чувак намеренно создал приложение, которое заставляло пользователей метать телефоны высоко в воздух и соответсвенно разбивать их об асфальт =). Но реализация вроде была тоже на GoogleAPI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думал, не найду, однако у Google API есть Elevation API, офигеть. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro?hl=ru

Answer (score 2):

Для получения высоты GPS приемника над уровнем моря используется 
[`Location.getAltitude()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAltitude()) (не забудьте сначала проверить, что `hasAltitude()` возвращает `true`)
Для получения уровня земли над уровнем моря в данной точке можно использовать 
[Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro?hl=ru)
Можно вычесть из первого второе и получить то, что вам надо, но надо учитывать, что любой GPS приемник выдает данные с погрешностью +